# How to limit a Kotlin sequence with a predicate caring about the next element?

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming

I need to address an API which returns chunked data.

```
val response = server.getChunk(request, chunkNumber)

data class PageInfo(
    val pageNumber: Int,
    val maxPages: Int
)
data class Response(
    val elements: List<Payload>,
    val pageInfo: PageInfo
)
```

I assume this API idempotent.

I can do something like that (**take 1**):

```
var i = 0
var maxPages: Int
val payloadTotal = mutableListOf<Payload>()
do {
    val response = server.getChunk(request, i++)
    maxPages = response.pageInfo.maxPages
    payloadTotal.addAll(response.payload)
} while (i < maxPages)
```

It works, but it's ugly.

**take 2**:

```
val partners = IntStream
    .iterate(0) { it + 1 }
    .asSequence()
    .map { server.getChunk(request, it) }
    .takeWhile { it.pageInfo.pageNumber < it.pageInfo.maxPages }
    .map { it.payload }
    .flatten()
    .toList()
```

It looks much nicer, but doesn't quite work as intended: since we check the takeWhile predicate after already requesting the server we will always end up doing one extra request. And since we don't know the maxPages value before we do the first request we can't use something like `take(n: Int)`.

So I ended up going with that code (**take 3**):

```
var maxPages = Int.MAX_VALUE
val partners = IntStream
    .iterate(0) { it + 1 }
    .asSequence()
    .takeWhile { it < maxPages }
    .map {
        server.getChunk(request, it)
            .also { response -> maxPages = response.pageInfo.maxPages }
    }
    .map { it.payload }
    .flatten()
    .toList()
```

It works. But then again, we use this extra state which I do not like.

Also, because of the "effectively final" restrictions this won't work in Java at all (and I would like it to as a bonus).

So how do I achieve the required behavior with a functional approach? Is there a way to do it without tracking any addition state outside of the pipeline?

*If such a way exists does it also translate to Java?

Comment: What do you mean by "this won't work in Java at all"? You can call Kotlin from Java code. Or do you mean "How would the same code look in Java"?

Comment: I mean that changing an external variable inside lambda expression won't work in Java

Comment: Ah yes of course. I didn't see that maxPages was dynamic. Wouldn't your take 2 work when you check with `<=` instead of `<`?

Comment: @Spitzbueb It will make it worse - that's gonna be two extra calls instead of one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create our own sequence operator for this purpose. It requires writing some code, but then we can use it very nicely:

```kotlin
generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }
    .map { server.getChunk(request, it) }
    .takeNextWhile { it.pageInfo.pageNumber + 1 < it.pageInfo.maxPages }
    .flatMap { it.elements }
    .toList()

fun <T> Sequence<T>.takeNextWhile(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Sequence<T> = Sequence {
    val iter = iterator()
    var hasNext = iter.hasNext()
    object : Iterator<T> {
        override fun hasNext() = hasNext
        override fun next() = iter.next().also { hasNext = iter.hasNext() && predicate(it) }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, we can name it `takeWhilePrevious()` if that makes more sense to us.

If we don't want to create new operators, then I think it is better to not use functional transformations at all as they worsen the code readability in this case. Assuming `maxPages` does not change, we can first get it and then perform a very simple loop:

```kotlin
val first = server.getChunk(request, 0)
val payloads = first.elements.toMutableList()
(1 until first.pageInfo.maxPages).forEach {
    payloads += server.getChunk(request, it).elements
}
```

Comment: I like the custom operator, although I'd probably make it `<T : Any>` because `null` elements would break `hasNext()` here (won't call the predicate)

Comment: @Joffrey Ahhh, right. I had another solution just minutes ago, storing `hasNext` instead of `curr`. It didn't have this problem.

Comment: @Joffrey I rolled back to the previous solution. It has a little drawback: it invokes `predicate` even if we don't plan to get next element. But this is a rather rare case, the code is easier to read and it doesn't have the problem mentioned by you. I think proper solution would be to introduce another variable to detect the first element. Sticking to `Any` is fine, but makes this function a little less flexible.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would probably just make a sequence out of a `do-while` loop. It's quite readable for those who need to read the implementation, and quite useful for those who just care about the sequence:

```kotlin
fun Server.requestInPages(request: Request, startPage: Int = 0): Sequence<Response> = sequence {
    var page = startPage
    do {
        val response = getChunk(request, page++)
        yield(response)
    } while (response.pageInfo.pageNumber < response.pageInfo.maxPages)
}
```

And then use it like this:

```kotlin
val partners = server.requestInPages(request)
    .flatMap { it.elements }
    .toList()
```

If the responses are all the same, you could even add another helper that contains the `flatMap` on top of `requestInPages`. If nobody cares about the response structure and `PageInfo` at all, you could even make the `flatMap` part of `requestInPages`.

Bonus points: this could even be turned into a flow if your API call becomes a `suspend` function at some point (e.g. if you switch to coroutines).

Comment: Hmm, does it make sense to invoke `asSequence()` inside `flatMap()`? We have a collection already, so we can't make it more lazy. I believe `Sequence.flatMap()` handles iterables and sequences in the same way - by acquiring an iterator.

Comment: @broot for some reason it didn't compile the first time I tried, so I just assumed sequences only supported `flatMap` with lambdas that produced sequences. But definitely no need for this if `Iterable` is supported (and indeed it is, I checked). I removed `asSequence()` there

Answer (score 0):

Little workaround to make it work, you can pass the null response object as seed to `generateSequence`

```
val partners = generateSequence(0 to (null as Response?)) { (page, _) ->
    page+1 to getChunk(page)
}.takeWhile { (page, response) ->
    response == null || page < response.maxPages
}.flatMap {
    it.second?.payload ?: emptyList()
}.toList()
```

(Readability goal is still not resolved though.) Some clarity can be introduced using functions

```
data class PageResponse(val page: Int = 0, val response: Response? = null) {
  fun isNotLastPage() = response == null || page < response.maxPages

  fun getPayload() = response?.payload ?: emptyList()
}

val partners = generateSequence(PageResponse()) { (page, _) ->
  PageResponse(page + 1, getChunk(page))
}
.takeWhile(PageResponse::isNotLastPage)
.flatMap(PageResponse::getPayload)
.toList()
```

Comment: Honestly, it's interesting for the effort, but please don't write this in production code. The loop in this case is hands down much more readable (it just needs to be extracted away into a function)